# In my root controller, how do I check if there's a child controller?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

My root controller performs push segues to some child controllers.

In my root controller, I want to check whether *there's a controller on top of self* **and** *that child controller is of type "MessageViewController"*

How can I perform that check in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController.viewControllers.count will tell you how many controllers are on the stack. If you're interested in the one directly above you, you can test if self.navigationController.viewControllers[1] (after checking that there are at least 2 controllers on the stack) is a MessageViewController.

```
    if self.navigationController!.viewControllers.count >= 2 {
        let vc = self.navigationController!.viewControllers[1] as! UIViewController
        if vc is MessageViewController {
            // do whatever
        }
    }
```

If the segues are modal presentations, you can check if the presentedViewController property is non nil,

```
    if let vc = self.presentedViewController {
        if vc is MessageViewController {
            // do whatever
        }
    }else{
        println("No presented view conttoller")
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on the first line. Is it because my root controller is not embedded in a navigation controller? (It's not...I just use "push")

Comment: @TIMEX, you can't do a push segue without using a navigation controller, so I assumed you had one. So what are you really doing?

Comment: I have 2 ViewControllers (generic ones).  I drag one of the view controllers onto the other view controller and select "show (eg. push"). That's it. Just a simple app like that.

Comment: @TIMEX A "Show" segue is only a "push" if the controller is embedded in a navigation controller; if not, it's equivalent to a modal presentation. I've edited my answer.